# C#.net 5 Manipulating download tasks with cancellation token

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Can someone help me understanding tasks?
I have downloads and want to cancel all current downloads when user closes the application, using cancellationtoken

I did it this way but I'm not sure if it is correct...

**The declaration of token controller:**

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
ConcurrentBag<Task> downloadTasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
```

**The task initialization:**

```
downloadTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => SaveStreamAsFile(pathToSave, streamInfo, fileToSave, token)));
```

**The download method:**

```
public static bool SaveStreamAsFile(string filePath, Stream inputStream, string fileName, CancellationToken ct) {

    try {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
        if (!info.Exists) {
            info.Create();
        }

        string path = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
        using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) {
            inputStream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log the exception 
    }
    return false;
}
```

**The cancel tasks method:**

```
public static async Task<bool> cancelAllTasks() {
    if (downloadTasks.Count == 0) return true;

    tokenSource.Cancel();

    try {
        await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    } catch (OperationCanceledException) {
        // task canceled log
        return false;
    } finally {
        tokenSource.Dispose();
    }

    return true;
}
```

**The Form Closing method:**

```
private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    var canExit = await cancelAllTasks();
    if (!canExit) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

The form closing method is confused for me because if canExit is false, user can't close the form forever??

Well, if someone can give me a point to a right way of using tasks, I'll appreciate because I have read documentation and examples but tasks in C# is something hard to understand for me yet.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> I have downloads and want to cancel all current downloads when user closes the application

Good news: you literally don't have to do anything. If your application exits, then downloads are automatically cancelled.

Remove your `Form1_FormClosing` event handler completely and it should work fine.

Comment: I was thinking in this but I don't know, the framework will do all the job for me?

Comment: @GnRSlashSP: No. The operating system will.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be, that if the operator tries to close the form, your application should react similar to how notepad reacts if the operator wants to close the notepad application:

- If all tasks are completed: just close
- It some tasks are not completed: warn the operator that some tasks will be cancelled.
- If the operator is ok with this: cancel the tasks, and when finished close the form
- If the operator is not ok with this: cancel closing the form.

To do this properly, you should make your methods awaitable:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveStreamAsFileAsync(string filePath, Stream inputStream,
    string fileName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        // does nothing if already exists

        string path = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
        using (var stream = File.Create(path)
        {
            await inputStream.CopyToAsync(stream, cancellationToken);
        }

        // if here, stream completely copied to the file
        return true;
    }
    catch (OperationCancelledException exc)
    {
         // TODO: how to react if operation cancelled?
         // TODO: check if the file must be deleted
    }
    catch (Exception ex)  // every other exception
    {
        // TODO: log
    }
    return false; // stream not saved
}
```

}

Your form has two properties: the DownLoadTask and the CancellationTokenSource:

```
private Task<bool> TaskDownLoad {get; set;} = Task.FromResult<false>();
private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource {get; set;} = null;

private CancellationTokenSource CreateCancellationTokenSource()
{
     return new CancellationTokenSource();
}
```

I use a separate method to create the CancellationTokenSource. If you want, you can add a check to see if there is already a CancellationTokenSource, and decide what to do if so: Only Dispose it and create a new one? Cancel creation of the new source and reuse the current one?

I need an extra Boolean property: IsCloseRequested. If true, then the Form must close as soon as the download task finishes or is cancelled.

```
private bool IsCloseRequested {get; set;} = false;
```

To start and cancel downloading:

```
private async Task DownloadAsync()
{
    // Show the operator that downloading is about to start, for instance ajax loader
    // also: prevent extra start by disabling buttons and menu items
    this.ShowDownloadStarted();

    string folder = ...;
    string fileName = ...;

    using (this.cancellationTokenSource = this.CreateCancellationTokenSource())
    {
        using (Stream source = ...)
        {
            bool fileSaved = await this.SaveStreamAsFileAsync(folder, source,
                fileName, this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            if (fileSaved)
            {
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    this.cancellationTokenSource = null;
    this.ShowDownloadFinished();

    if (this.IsCloseRequested)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

While Downloading you need to assert that no second download will be started, so disable buttons / menu items that can start a second download. Also show the operator that a download has been started.

```
private void CancelDownload()
{
    this.CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
}
```

I expect that cancelling your download does not take a considerable amount of time. If not, consider to show the operator that cancellation is requested: hourglass cursor, or maybe even some information in a panel.

Start Downloading for instance because of ButtonClick:

```
private async void OnButtonStartDownload_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    await this.DownloadAsync();
}

private void OnButtonCancelDownload_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.CancelDownload();
}
```

I don't do a lot in the event handlers, maybe you also have other methods to start downloading, for instance because of a menu click, or maybe event Form Load. Also: maybe you want one button to start and cancel downloading.

### Back to your question

After these changes Closing the form is easy:

```
private bool IsTaskBusy => !this.TaskDownLoad.IsCompleted;

private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
(
    if (this.IsTaskBusy)
    {
        // We can't close right now; we'll have to wait until task is finished
        e.Cancel = true;

        // warn operator and ask if cancellation is allowed
        bool cancellationAllowed = this.AskIfCancellationAllowed();
        if (cancellationAllowed)
        {
            this.CancelDownload();
            this.IsCloseRequested = true;
        }
    }
    // else: no task running: we can continue closing
}
```

So if the operator tries to close the form while a task is still running, the form won't close. Using a MessageBox ask the operator if cancellation is allowed.

- If not: don't close the form
- If cancellation allowed: also don't close the form, but cancel the task and remember that the from closing is requested.

Whenever the task completes, either because of cancellation, or because of completion, `Close()` is called. This time there is no running task, so the form will Close immediately.

This method has the advantage, that the operator can also choose to cancel the download without closing the form.